# Expression Tree checking column value is in list of ints

Tags: c#, expression, expression-trees

Just to help with the question I am trying to find a way to search a database column 'ID'for any row that has a match to a list of ints.

for example the db might have id's 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 6

and i have a list of ints { 1 , 3, 5 } and i want to find any of the ids in the list

I have so far...

```
//list of ints
dynamic constant = Expression.Constant(value);

List<int> ids = constant.Value;

Expression<Func<Invoice, bool>> test = (Invoice inv) => ids.Contains(inv.ID);

return Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new Type[] { }, constant, test);
```

I then add this expression to any of the others and call

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<Invoice, bool>>(finalexpression, parameter);
```

The error I am getting is

```
No method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied arguments.
```

Any help is appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

[`Enumerable.Any`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534972(v=vs.110).aspx) is a **generic** method with one generic type argument. You should supply that argument to the [`Expression.Call`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351107(v=vs.110).aspx) overload used through `Type[] typeArguments` parameter:

```
return Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable), "Any", new Type[] { typeof(Invoice) } /* <== here */,
    constant, test);
```

P.S. These two lines

```
var constant = Expression.Constant(value);
List<int> ids = constant.Value;
```

look suspicious (the second line does not compile at all). To make the sample working, the `List<int> ids` variable must be initialized somewhere else and the `value` variable should hold `IEnumerable<Invoice>` instance.

Comment: using that chnage I still get the same error - No generic method 'Any' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments.

Comment: value is the list of ints sorry but in string form i parse it then create a constant of the type using Expression.Constant(value, Type.GetType(newType == null ? filter.Type : newType));

Comment: sorry why should value be Ienumerable<invoice> ? when the list of ids i want to search is a list of ints?

Comment: Because `test` predicate expects `Invoice`: `(Invoice inv) => ids.Contains(inv.ID)`. So basically it can be used like `IEnumerable<Invoice> invoices = ...; bool result = invoices.Any(inv => ids.Contains(inv.ID));`. If that's not what you want, please update the question accordingly.